# Notifications consent isn't saved

Tags: javascript

Testing the notifications API.

I followed the example here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API

I get the prompt to give my consent, however even when I give it the internal state still isn't granted.

The origin of the issue, I assume, is that I am running the file in the browser, meaning that it isn't hosted on a web server, I am using a `file://...` to access it, but I couldn't find a place saying that this should be the issue.

Bellow is the code:

```
if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
  var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
  setTimeout(notification.close.bind(notification), 1000);
} else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
  Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
    if (permission === "granted") {
      var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      setTimeout(notification.close.bind(notification), 1000);
    }
  });
} else {
  alert("Notification access denied.");
}
```

---

Trying to figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: I suppose, that notification settings (allow or deny) link with domains (or web-sites). So if there is no domain, how it may know can it show notification or not? And, as mentioned, this future available in WebWorker. And WebWorker, I supposed, need to know in wich domain it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Chrome, it doesn't allow cookies on local files. You could just host a webserver with for example xampp or wampp and serve the page there. This would allow for cookies to be set.